# Set Category Group Visibility Settings for Role using Apex

Tags: apex, metadata-api, role-hierarchy, roles, data-category

The question is can I set Category Group Visibility Settings for Role using Apex code somehow? My logic creates Data Categories (I'm using Metadata Api for it) and User Roles (I'm using UserRole object for it) automatically, but the problem is that the Data Category Group visibility for new generated Roles are custom by default (except the main role - the visibility is 'All' by default). What I need is visibility 'None' by default for all child roles, but I did not find the way to configure it using Apex even with the help of Metadata Api. Is it even possible?

Comment: What type of org are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sandbox, Alberto.

Comment: I'm also looking for answer on this